# Upward confluence in the interaction calculus

Tags: lambda-calculus, term-rewriting-systems, interaction-nets

The lambda calculus is not upward confluent, [counterexamples](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Take-Ve-an-Easy-Expansion-Exercise-Oostrom/c179a23274c06aaca4865a2e3c66a45612c38aa0) being known for a long time. Now, what about the [interaction calculus](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/10704567_10)? Specifically, I am looking for configurations $c_1$ and $c_2$ such that $\exists c: c_1 \rightarrow^* c\ \wedge\ c_2 \rightarrow^* c$, but $\nexists c': c' \rightarrow^* c_1\ \wedge\ c' \rightarrow^* c_2$.

**Update**: a necessary and sufficient condition for strong upward confluence discussed in [arXiv:1806.07275v3](https://arxiv.org/abs/1806.07275v3) which also shows that the condition is not necessary for upward confluence by showing upward confluence for the interaction system of the linear lambda calculus.

Comment: Cross-posted to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/303045/upward-confluence-in-the-interaction-calculus